# MVC 5 HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, iis-8

i have got this problem where if i call url like this

```
http://localhost:5330/Admin/
```

it throws me

```
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
```

while giving like this works fine

```
http://localhost:5330/Admin/Index
```

Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
-->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>

  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <globalization uiCulture="es-US" culture="es-US"></globalization>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="Kendo.Mvc.UI" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <!--register windows login managed handler.-->
      <add name="Windows Login Handler" path="Login" type="CSP.Web.WindowsLoginHandler" verb="GET,POST" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30AD4FE6B2A6AEED" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31BF3856AD364E35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.2.0" newVersion="5.2.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.2.0" newVersion="5.2.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.2.0" newVersion="5.2.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>

  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="500000000" />
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>

  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlClient.4.0" />
      <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Provider 4.0" invariant="System.Data.SqlClient.4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server" type="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
</configuration>
```

Global.asax.cs:

```
using CSP.Web.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace CSP.Web
{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        public MvcApplication()
        {
            this.RegisterWindowsAuthentication();
        }
        protected void Application_Start()
        {

            Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(null);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
        protected void Application_Error()
        {

            HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;

            System.Exception exe = ctx.Server.GetLastError();
            //if (exe.Message.Contains("undefined"))
            //{
            //    return;
            //}
            //else
            //{
            KeyValuePair<string, object> error = new KeyValuePair<string, object>("ErrorMessage", ctx.Server.GetLastError().ToString());
            CSP.Web.Helpers.Log objLog = new CSP.Web.Helpers.Log();
            objLog.LogError(ctx.Server.GetLastError().ToString());
            ctx.Response.Clear();
            Response.Redirect(String.Format("/Error/{0}", "ShowError"));
            ctx.Server.ClearError();
            //ctx.Response.End();
            //}

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

That is probably correct behavior. When you invoke /Admin/, it tries to list the contents of that folder, which is of course forbidden by IIS (by default). Invoking /Admin/Index takes you to the `Index()` action of the `AdminController`.

Your solution would be to set up default routing so that /Admin/ forwards to /Admin/Index. Make sure you have the below lines somewhere in your `Global.asax.cs`:

```
// Default MVC route (fallback)
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

Comment: I have them in RouteConfig. Will that be ok

Comment: @Vivekh Should be fine, as long as that code runs when the web application boots...

Comment: Yes its running when application starts but i am facing the same error

Comment: @Vivekh What version of IIS are you on? Can you post your web.config?

Comment: @Vivekh Thanks... And is the default route above the last route to get registered in global.asax.cs? It has to be at the end... Maybe post your global.asax.cs as well if you don't mind.

Comment: @Vivekh Is your `AdminController` a separate Area, or is it a controller on the root of the site? I.e. is `AdminController.cs` located in \Web\Controllers, or \Areas\Admin\Controllers?

Comment: No its just loacated at controllers\AdminController.cs

Comment: Hey do hidden folders comes into picture if there is a folder named Account though its not in controller section ?

Comment: @Vivekh No, they shouldn't. Sorry, I forgot that you are using MVC 5... Can you actually also post `App_Start\RouteConfig.cs`? Last file, I promise!